# How can you solve an augmented Matrix in swift?

Tags: swift, matrix, accelerate

Say you have this augmented Matrix:

```
1 1 0 0 = 1

0 0 1 1 = 1

40 10 40 10 <=50
```

I've tried using the accelerate framework but despite a couple hrs and a lot of google I can't figure this one out. Is there a reasonable way to solve this in Swift?

Comment: Have you looked at [this article](http://connor-johnson.com/2015/10/17/solving-linear-equations-with-swift-and-accelerate/)?

Comment: Read it now, thank you and good news it works, bad news is I didn't understand my original problem well enough to realize this wouldn't be enough.